# How to set position of MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I want to set the default position of the **MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES** installation page while installation, which is now at upper left corner of the screen. I need to change the page position to the center of the screen. How should I do it? Unable to find anything on web regarding this any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Like centering whole installer window?

Comment: Yes like that only.

Comment: Why do you think it is a good idea to move the window? The user should be in control over where their windows are on the screen.

Comment: @Anders why dnt u think its good idea to do all the things at one position only rather than showing one welcome page at center , instfiles page at upper left corner, uninst page at upper left corner? If there is a way to do it I want to do it, why I want to do it that shouldn't be your concern.

Comment: It should be pretty obvious why it is a bad idea. The user might have some program that automatically positions windows or perhaps they like to use the taskbars "windows side by side" command and if you force things like this on the user you just annoy them.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear to me if you want to center the window when the user starts the installer or when they get to the InstFiles page (which is normally not the first page).

Either way, you can call this function to center the window:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!ifndef SPI_GETWORKAREA
!define SPI_GETWORKAREA 0x0030
!endif
Function CenterWindowOnCurrentMonitor
System::Store S
System::Call '*(i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i)i.r9' ; Allocate a RECT/MONITORINFO struct
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(i$hwndParent, ir9)'
System::Call '*$9(i.r1,i.r2,i.r3,i.r4)' ; Extract data from RECT
IntOp $3 $3 - $1 ; Window width
IntOp $4 $4 - $2 ; Window height
System::Call "User32::SystemParametersInfo(i${SPI_GETWORKAREA}, i0, ir9, i0)"
System::Call '*$9(i.r5,i.r6,i.r7,i.r8)' ; Extract data from RECT
System::Call 'USER32::MonitorFromWindow(i$hwndParent, i1)i.r0'
${If} $0 <> 0
    System::Call '*$9(i40)' ; Set MONITORINFO.cbSize
    System::Call 'USER32::GetMonitorInfo(ir0, ir9)i.r0'
    ${IfThen} $0 <> 0 ${|} System::Call "*$9(i,i,i,i,i,i.r5,i.r6,i.r7,i.r8)" ${|} ; Extract data from MONITORINFO
${EndIf}
System::Free $9
IntOp $7 $7 - $5 ; Workarea width
IntOp $8 $8 - $6 ; Workarea height
IntOp $7 $7 / 2
IntOp $8 $8 / 2
IntOp $1 $5 + $7 ; Left = Workarea left + (Workarea width / 2)
IntOp $2 $6 + $8 ; Top = Workarea top + (Workarea height / 2)
IntOp $3 $3 / 2
IntOp $4 $4 / 2
IntOp $1 $1 - $3 ; Left -= Window width / 2
IntOp $2 $2 - $4 ; Top -= Window height / 2
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(i$hwndParent, i, ir1, ir2, i, i, i 0x211)' ; NoSize+NoZOrder+NoActivate
System::Store L
FunctionEnd
```

To center it on the InstFiles page:

```
Section
Call CenterWindowOnCurrentMonitor
SectionEnd
```

To center it when the installer starts:

```
; Optional: !include MUI2.nsh

!ifdef MUI_INCLUDED

!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT CenterWindowOnCurrentMonitor
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

!else

Function .onGuiInit
Call CenterWindowOnCurrentMonitor
FunctionEnd

Page Components
Page InstFiles

!endif
```